# Reading Data in C From Socket Until End Character

Tags: c, sockets

EDIT: It has been proven in the comments that defining the length instead should produce the same results and would not use any significant extra data. If you are looking for a way to send data between machines running your program(s), sending the length is better than reading until a terminating character. BonzaiThePenguin has some very good points you should look at.

But for educational purposes: I never found good example code that does this for standard C sockets that handles situations where the data is not all received in one packet, or multiple separate messages are contained within one packet. Simply calling recv repeatedly will not work in all cases.

This is one of those questions where I've answered it myself below, but I'm not 100% confident in my response.

Comment: That's like suggesting we go back to null-terminated C strings.

Comment: Wanted to add: not only are terminators the *cause* of countless more buffer over-reads, but the terminator itself is usually allowed to appear in the middle of the data (like the Unicode null character), so it will break functionality unless you wrap the data in some container format. One simple container format involves *providing the length*.

Comment: It depends on what you're using it for. If you want to send really small data, wrapping it in headers could double how much data you are transmitting over the network. If you're sending really small data very many times, this can be a big performance problem. I admit the reason in my question isn't very good, but nowhere did I suggest that we all use this.

Comment: The terminator can't be any smaller than one byte, so it seems like using a variable-length encoding format for the length field (similar to UTF8) would work just as well, wouldn't it?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but if you're going to use variable-length encoding format, you need at least 2 bytes: one for the length, one to terminate the length field. Otherwise, there is no way to know how many bytes to read for the length.

Comment: Not true, you should look up how UTF8 encoding works. As a very simple VLE example: if the upper bit of the first byte is NOT set then it's one byte (for lengths of 0 to 127), otherwise it's 4 bytes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

Comment: Yes, that works. I now accept that there's no advantage of checking for a terminating character unless you care about that one or few extra byte(s) for lengths of longer transmissions (which should be essentially never). I'm going to put a warning label on the question and leave it there just in case someone wants to know how to use character termination for whatever reason.

Comment: @BonzaiThePenguin what is wrong with C strings?

Comment: @phyrrus9 I was going to ask the same thing… All the libraries I'm using in my school project (cURL, cJSON, etc) require null-terminated strings.

Comment: @9000 the issue I suspect are, some people religiously use the string class, vectors, etc when they are neither useful nor necessary. There is no reason to not use C strings. For traffic at least. The only thing a string class is good for is dynamic allocation. Other than that, (and even that can be done with resizing when needed) the string class is useless in comparison.

Comment: @phyrrus9 I explained what was wrong with them *in my very next post*, but you were apparently too focused on trying to turn it into a "religious" argument to notice. Since NUL is a valid Unicode codepoint you can't safely use raw C strings for most things.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't 'dangerous to allow the client to specify the size of the message it is sending'. Most of the protocols in the word do that, including HTTP and SSL. It's only dangerous when implementations don't bounds-check messages properly.

The fatal flaw with your suggestion is that it doesn't work for binary data: you have to introduce an escape character so that the terminating character can appear within a message, and then of course you also need to escape the escape. All this adds processing and data copying at both ends.

Comment: doesn't HTTP have a content-length field in the header?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with. I cannot guarantee that this is perfect because I am not a professional, so if there are any mistakes, I (and anyone else looking for help) would greatly appreciate it if someone would point them out.

Context: socket is the socket, buffer is the array that stores all network input, line is the array that stores just one message extracted from buffer (which is what the rest of your program uses), length is the length of both inputted arrays, and recvLength is a pointer to an integer stored outside of the function that is meant to be 0 initially and should not be freed or modified by anything else. That is, it should persist across multiple calls to this function on the same socket. This function returns the length of the data outputted in the line array.

```
size_t recv_line(int socket, char* buffer, char* line, size_t length, size_t* recvLength){ //receives until '\4' (EOT character) or '\0' (null character)

size_t readHead = 0;
size_t lineIndex = 0;
char currentChar = 0;
while (1){
    for (; readHead < *recvLength; readHead = readHead + 1){
        currentChar = buffer[readHead];
        if (currentChar=='\4' || currentChar=='\0'){ //replace with the end character(s) of your choice
            if (DEBUG) printf("Received message===\n%s\n===of length %ld\n", line, lineIndex+1);
            memcpy(buffer, buffer + readHead + 1, length-(readHead)); //shift the buffer down
            *recvLength -= (readHead + 1); //without the +1, I had an "off by 1" error before!
            return lineIndex+1; //success
        }
        if (readHead >= length){
            if (DEBUG) printf("Client tried to overflow the input buffer. Disconnecting client.\n");
            *recvLength = 0;
            return 0;
        }
        line[lineIndex] = currentChar;
        lineIndex++;
    }
    *recvLength = recv(socket, buffer + readHead, length, 0);
}
printf("Unknown error in recv_line!\n");
return 0;

}
```

Simple example usage:

```
int function_listening_to_network_input(int socket){
char netBuffer[2048];
char lineBuffer[2048];
size_t recvLength = 0;

while (1==1){
size_t length = recv_line(socket, netBuffer, lineBuffer, 2048, &recvLength);
// handle it…
}
return 0;
}
```

Note that this does not always leave line as a null-terminated string. If you want it to, it's easy to modify.

Comment: I suggest that you should show some code using this function.  It would probably help explain why the two buffers have to be passed to the function, and the role of `recvLength` and why it can't be changed.  Writing such canonical 'how to use' code is often a good idea — you should be able to include it as a comment in the header that declares this function for others to use.  I'm also curious; should there be a `send_line()` function analogous to this?  And what about if I want to send arbitrary binary data (say raw encrypted data, with every byte value from 0 through 255 possible)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'll edit the answer to include example usage, but as explained above, it's better to read until a certain length (defined by the client) instead. With this method, you cannot send arbitrary binary data because the terminating byte might be included in it. The send_line() function doesn't need to be like this, but you need to make sure whatever is sending ends with the terminating byte.

Comment: The purpose of recvLength is so that if two separate strings are received in the buffer together, recv_line "remembers" how much leftover data is in the buffer after the first call so it can read that first next time you call recv_line.